# "It's time that someone looked you in the eyes and told it to you straight."

Tags: tense, subjunctives

Could anyone tell me why the verbs "look and tell" are in the past tense in the following sentence:

> It's time that someone looked you in the eyes and told it to you straight.

Answer (score 1):

It's the use of the past for *irrealis* or *counter-factual* clauses. It's very much like

> If someone looked you in the eyes and told it to you straight ...

So with the past, this is counter-factual, and implies "but nobody is going to do that". Contrast

> If, when you get there, somebody looks you in the eyes and tells you straight ....

which is not counter-factual: it may yet happen.

(Historically this is past subjunctive, but since there is now precisely **one** word in the language for which this is different from the past - *were* vs *was* - I don't think this is a helpful description of modern English.)

Comment: I was going to say it's nearly always singular *look you in the **eye***, but I just checked NGrams to see that things seem to have changed quite a bit in just the last couple of decades. The plural now accounts for about a quarter of all AmE instances (but 90% of all BrE usages are still singular).